# How to declare final HashMap that should not allow to update or remove element

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have a hash map like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Map<String, String> daysMap = new HashMap(7);
    daysMap.put("1", "Sunday");
    daysMap.put("2", "Monday");
    daysMap.put("3", "Tuesday");
    daysMap.put("4", "Wednesday");
    daysMap.put("5", "Thursday");
    daysMap.put("6", "Friday");
    daysMap.put("7", "Saturday");
}
```

In this map 
1. Should not allow to put more than 7 elements 
2. Should not update value for corresponding key [like daysMap.put("5", "xxx");]
3. Should not allow to remove any key

How to do?

Comment: Java? Are all values known at compile time?

Comment: Yes java. We don't know at compile time.

Comment: BTW The capacity will end up being the default of `16` here so setting it to `7` won't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement a new HashMap

```
public class CoolMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {

@Override
public V put(K key, V value) {

    if (size() == 7) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Size is at max!");
    } else {

        // If there is something already with that key
        if (containsKey(value)) {
            // do nothing
            return value;
        } else {
            // put inside
            return super.put(key, value);
        }

    }

}

@Override
public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> collection) {

    if (collection.size() > 7) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Size is at max!");
    } else {
        super.putAll(collection);
    }

}

@Override
public V remove(Object key) {
    return null;// doesn't remove anything
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Points 2 and 3 are covered by [`Collections.unmodifiableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap%28java.util.Map%29). To cover the first point, you can add an hand written test.

Answer (score 1):

As has been already discussed ,the Points 2 and 3 are covered like this

```
import java.util.*;

    public class OP2 {
       public static void main(String[] s) {
          //object hash table 
          Hashtable<String,String> table = new Hashtable<String,String>();
          table.

          // populate the table
          table.put("1", "Sunday");
          table.put("2", "Monday");
          table.put("3", "Tuesday");
          table.put("4", "Wednesday");
          table.put("5", "Thursday");
          table.put("6", "Friday");
          table.put("7", "Saturday");

          System.out.println("Initial collection: "+table);

          // create unmodifiable map
          Map m = Collections.unmodifiableMap(table);

          // try to modify the collection
         // m.put("key3", "value3");
         //Uncomment the above line and an error is obtained
       }
    }
```

Moreover for the first problem it would be better to call a function when you populate your map:-

```
 public boolean putAndTest(MyKey key, MyValue value) {
            if (map.size() >= MAX && !map.containsKey(key)) {
                 return false;
            } else {
                 map.put("Whatever you want");
                 return true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t you create your own object that contains a private hashmap and then you can allow what methods on that private hashmap that are made public?